# Facing problem regarding 'QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED' when imoprting data from QB to DB

Tags: php, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I was trying to import customer data from QB to db using XML. I am getting 'Complete!' message while running my qwc file through web connector. The problem I'm facing I'm providing below,

1. There is total 67 records in Quickbooks, but we are getting only 60 records in local DB after running the file in web connector.
2. If I increase the QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED to 100 or something else for the first time when importing data, records are not coming in MySQL db. We can have much more records in QB, so what is the solution should be here.
3. All the records we are importing into db is having IsActive value 0 in MySQL db.
   We are very near to our success point but can't reach to it. Please guide us with your suggestion.

My code bunch is available at github, the qwc file is located at https://github.com/moumita-ray/quickbooks-xml/blob/master/customer_import.qwc and the php file is at https://github.com/moumita-ray/quickbooks-xml/blob/master/customer_import.php

Comment: Put the Web Connector in VERBOSE mode. Delete all records from quickbooks_queue table. Run the Web Connector.  Post the log file from the Web Connector.

Comment: Done as per instruction. Same data is getting imported by WC. Here is the log file -------------------------------------------------------------
20190527.06:10:55 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20190527.06:10:55 UTC : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20190527.06:10:55 UTC :  : ~SingleInstanceHandler() - usingInstanceChannel = false. Returning without any Registry key delete or unmarshalling.

Comment: Your log file is only 1 line long?

Comment: Put the Web Connector in VERBOSE mode, also changed $log_level = QUICKBOOKS_LOG_VERBOSE; in php file. My QWCLog file is at, https://github.com/moumita-ray/quickbooks-xml/blob/master/QWCLog.txt

Comment: The log file you posted is incomplete. It's missing about 70% of the file. Where are you getting your count of 67 customers from?

Comment: Are you sure some of your customers aren't marked inactive? You're only querying for active customers.

Comment: I came to know about the count from MySQL `qb_customer` table as well as from QB desktop interface. In QB also there are 67 records showing. In QB all the customers are marked active only, though only few customers are not getting imported in db. Is there any settings or anything which is preventing those specific records to import. Only last few rows are not getting imported. If you want I can send my MySQL table for reference. I checked with raw data to compare, but have no clue. Please guide.